# NG-ZORRO modal component in lazy loaded component, close button destroy event not triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules, ng-zorro-antd, angular12

I am using Ng-zorro to display a custom modal component inside a lazy loaded component:

component used to display custom modal:

```
showArtistModal(artist: any): void {
this.modalService.create({
  nzContent: ArtistModalComponent,
  nzComponentParams: {
    artist,
  },
  nzCentered: true,
  // nzOnOk: () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)),
  // nzFooter: [
  //   {
  //     label: 'Close',
  //     shape: 'round',
  //     onClick: () => modal.destroy(),
  //   },
  //   {
  //     label: 'Confirm',
  //     type: 'primary',
  //     onClick: () => modal.destroy(),
  //   },
  // ],
})}
```

custom modal component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NzModalRef } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-modal',
  templateUrl: './artist-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artist-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ArtistModalComponent {
  @Input() artist;

  constructor(private modal: NzModalRef) {}

  destroyModal(): void {
    this.modal.destroy();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <div *nzModalTitle>
    {{artist.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    truc
  </div>
  <div *nzModalFooter>
    <button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="destroyModal()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Components
import { ArtistModalComponent } from './artist-modal/artist-modal.component';

// NgZorro Components
import { NzGridModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/grid';
import { NzCardModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/card';
import { NzModalModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NzCardModule, NzGridModule, NzModalModule, NzButtonModule],
  exports: [
    ArtistModalComponent,
    NzCardModule,
    NzGridModule,
    NzModalModule,
    NzButtonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ArtistModalComponent],
})
export class SharedModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

But I cannot close the modal when it is displayed, the destroy() event is not triggered and the closing button is not working. Am I missing something ? Already tried to move everything in the same module as the component used to display the modal but it is still not working.
I am using Angular 12.

Comment: From the docs: All the `NzModalService.methods` will return a reference, and then we can close the popup by the reference: 
`constructor(modal: NzModalService) {
  const ref: NzModalRef = modal.info();
  ref.close(); // Or ref.destroy(); This dialog will be destroyed directly
}`

Comment: Yes but I am using a custom modal component, I tried to add this to my custom modal component but it is creating a new modal on top of my custom one. In the doc they also show this `export class NzModalCustomFooterComponent {
  constructor(private modal: NzModalRef) {}

  destroyModal(): void {
    this.modal.destroy();
  }
}`

Comment: So it should already work, no need I think to add again the NzModalService in my custom modal component

Comment: And even when doing this, the new modal created won't close neither...

Comment: have you verified that the modal is correctly referenced? how about the some consoles on `this.modal` inside the destroy function triggered by the click of the 'close'-button? Always remember: F12 is your friend.. ;)

Comment: Yes I tried this also, I am receiving this log in the destroyModal function `He {overlayRef: mt, config: {…}, containerInstance: t, componentInstance: t, state: 0, …}
afterClose: e {closed: false, observers: Array(1), isStopped: false, hasError: false........`

Comment: So I think it is rightly referenced

Comment: yes, that doesn't seem to be the issue..

Comment: Could you maybe provide your specific example on stackblitz? - I'll try to find out the issue later after I finished work ;)

Comment: Thanks ! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uju567?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: No worries - I'll reply back once I found out whats going on here..